# How to perform cross-domain http request in Ionic Framework on Android?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-domain

How to perform cross-domain http request in Ionic Framework on Android?

I tried to set proxy in ionic.project, doesn't help. Here's how I do the request:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8100/getnews/?hashcode=' + hashcode + '').then(function (resp) {
        ...
    }, function (err) {
        ...
    }
```

Here's ionic.project:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "app_id": "...",
  "proxies": [
      {
        "path": "/getnews",
        "proxyUrl": "http://yukigaru.pythonanywhere.com/getnews/"
      }
    ]
}
```

It doesn't work on Android, function (err) branch is always called. It works on one computer's browser and doesn't work on another PC's browser.

Cordova 5.0.0, Ionic 1.3.20, Android 5.x.

Comment: are you using phonegapp or cordova ? if so make sure the access origin is set correctly  see: [cross origin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)

Comment: which browser are you talking About? chrome? ie?

Comment: Are you using the version 4 of the cordova-android platform or a older version? if using version 4, you have to make sure you have the  cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin in your project.

Comment: I'm using cordova 5.0.0.

Comment: Kenneth, don't pay attention to the browser issue, it's more issue with "not working on Android"

Comment: You may be using cordova 5, but unless you live in the future I don't think you have version 5 of the android platform... So my question was have you installed and configured the whitelist plugin? I suggest yoo have a look at this page : https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/

Comment: I've just tried the plugin, did everthing that the article says, but it doesn't help ((

Comment: @Juster: did you manage to solve your issue in the end?

Comment: This Ionic blog post is a good read about the subject: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing in my Ionic app is that I added this to the PHP file which plays as JSON API (and which I call from Ionic app):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

So, if you control your API endpoint server and are able to make similar (you didn't mention which API stack you use?) changes, you should be fine. *If anyone has a better use case, please respond...*

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is "this machine", that's why it works on the machine with the server and doesn't work on other machines.

Change `localhost` to the local IP of the machine with the server, something like `192.168.1.X`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call service outside of your origin then you should add Access Control Headers in the server side, else instead of $http.get you can try  $http.jsonp (i didnt try this method).

I Hope this will help you.